# Laravel 4 API with OAuth 2

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-4

I work on project based on Laravel 4 and I will provide Rest API, want to authenticate request using OAuth 2,

I try https://packagist.org/packages/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

but when try to run

```
Route::post('oauth/access_token', function()
{
    return AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();
});
```

I recieved

```
Class 'AuthorizationServer' not found
```

how to solve this? or there are another tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't followed the installation instructions provided by the package.

[oauth2-server-laravel on GitHub](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel)

Add the following line to your composer.json file:

> "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel": "1.0.x"

Add this line of code to the providers array located in your app/config/app.php file:

> 'LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\OAuth2ServerServiceProvider',

And these lines to the aliases array:

> 'AuthorizationServer' => 'LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\AuthorizationServerFacade',
>   'ResourceServer' => 'LucaDegasperi\OAuth2Server\Facades\ResourceServerFacade',

Answer (score 2):

Check if the `AuthorizationServer` is in another Namespace. If this is the case, use that Namespace before the class name, e.g. `Namespace\AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();`

If that doesn't work, try adding a `\` before the class name, like this: `\AuthorizationServer::performAccessTokenFlow();`

Comment: no it's not inside Namespace, and try "\" not solve the problem

Comment: where is your AuthorizationServer class located?

Comment: it's installed in Laravel, https://packagist.org/packages/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Comment: Did you make sure that you have included the path in the `$providers` array within the `~/app/config/app.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try those commands?

- composer update
- composer dumpautoload
- php artisan dump-autoload